# JQueryUI tabs. Stay in same tab after refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a basic pages with `JQuery UI` tabs. Something like this example:

```
 <div id="tabs">
 <ul>
    <li id="someid-1"><a href="#tabs-1">Start</a></li>
    <li id="someid-2"><a href="finish.php">Finish</a></li>
...
```

But if i'm in tab `Finish` on submit or refresh user is redirected into page `Start`. Is it possible to stay in same page if user submitting to `self` or refreshing?

Comment: append the id of the tab to teh form action. `action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>#tabs-1"`

Comment: Are you submitting a form? If so, why not make use of AJAX to send the form data without reloading?

Comment: @Twisty. Sometimes yes and sometimes no. Yes i can use ajax but how about just refresh a page? Is a possible to stay in same tab?